# CiviVolunteer: need link for Joomla

Tags: joomla, civivolunteer

I am using CiviVolunteer with Joomla and I am trying to enable the volunteer Opportunity Listing. I tried the following link the http://address-to-your-site/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities link with my domain and I am not able to see it. I have angular profiles enabled, and I granted access to AJAX API and CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer to anonymous users, but I am still not able to see this list publicly.
I have found the link for wordpress, but there is no documentation for Joomla. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don’t have a Joomla instance with CiviVolunteer but try this -

/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

Comment: I tried, get a page with header "CiviVolunteer" and blank below that. So this issue is likely more than the page link.

Comment: Anil - MillerTech answered the question, how do i flag it as answered?

Comment: I've just made my original comment an answer which can be accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have a Joomla instance with CiviVolunteer but try this -

/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities